# Unable to use flip card: target portal already aligned

Tags: ingress

I tried to use a Jarvis virus on blue portals and I got the following error when I confirmed the dialog:
**Unable to use flip card: target portal already aligned.**

The animation started, but nothing happened...

Does anybody have this issue too?
Could you help me to solve this error?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you Enlightened or Resistance?

Comment: I'm playing as green, and I put some Jarvis to blue portals in the past months and all of them worked well.

Comment: This looks more like a synch error. Sometimes it happen. Have you tried resynching or rebooting the app?

Comment: This is a very good option! I forgot this feature, I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm getting this message right now on a portal that was flipped recently. I assume that it is always the message shown when the flip does not work… Whatever the reason. It could be your level is too low, or that the portal has been flipped too recently.

Comment: I have not tested but would assume that you also get this error message when trying to use the wrong flip-card on a portal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this issue as well. Apperently its just a poorly worded error message. It should say you dont have enough XM to use the virus. There's a couple different formulas that I found listed:

- XM cost = (portal level * 1000) + 1﻿
- XM cost = (your level + 2) * 1000

Either way, if the portal you are attacking is a few levels above you, you'll probably get that error.

Ref:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/117085684342779518800/posts/AaY5P71EdRp

Answer (score -1):

This is not a poorly worded error message...

This has happened to me several times now and I am lvl8 with maxed out XM.

The first time it happened to me I had just used a Jarvis to flip the next closest portal that was fairly close. When the first one flipped it looked like both portals were flipping but they didn't. When I went to flip the second one it says... "Target portal already aligned." Which greatly upset me because it wasn't.

Today I tried to use a single Jarvis virus and I ran into the same problem and error message. I looked at the next closest portal and saw that someone else had used a Jarvis on it.

Both instances that this happened to me the next closest portal was recently flipped using a Jarvis.

I haven't tested this yet but... I'd like to see what happens if I attack the problematic portal with a single burster and then try to flip it so that the game understands that it is in fact still blue.

Comment: The Jarvis and Ada rules were change at newest version of ingress, so if somebody use a Jarvis or an Ada on a portal, you have to wait an hour to flip back. I tried a lot of possibility at the past but I did not find a clear answer ...